# Custom layout extending 2columns-left.xml problem

Tags: magento2, layout, frontend

I'm trying to create a custom layout based on **2columns-left.xml**. The layout was created correctly and I can select it from the Admin. This is what I did so far:

I created the **layouts.xml** file `THEME/Magento_Theme/layouts.xml`

And then I created the **customlayout.xml** file `THEME/Magento_Theme/page_layout/customlayout.xml`
With the same content as:

> vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/page_layout/2columns-left.xml

The problem is that the layout has only 1 column, instead of 2columns-left, why?

Thank you.

This is a repeat of the Custom Layout extending 2 columns left, there was no response and I would like to get this issue solved thanks!

Comment: can you please share your layout file code?

Comment: I tried the code below. I have a cms page that i am trying to give a custom layout but i want to keep the two column platform. I have a cms page with a hierarchy that I would like to keep on the page. Do i have to include anything more than just the code below to get that sidebar to appear again.

Comment: Can you provide anymore insight to accomplish this? @AliEjaz

Comment: @BrandonIrwin Did you get solution? I had face same issue.

Comment: I opened up a ticket with Magento about this in working with a few Magento Devs I know and this is what they came up with. I am not sure if they updated the devdocs since then I told them that would be helpful. Hope this helps

Hope this information will help.
The referenced documentation page (https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-create.html) contains an example of how to create a new layout, which declares an empty container for the footer content which will need to be designed.

Comment: According to the description of the container (https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#fedg_layout_xml-instruc_ex_cont), “If the <container> is empty, and there is no child <block> available, it will not be displayed in the frontend source code.”
So seeing the attached example layout in the layout selection menu on the entity editing page and not seeing a double footer on the frontend page seems like an expected system behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your handle like,

```
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
<update handle="2columns-left"/>
<referenceContainer name="columns">
    <container name="div.sidebar.main" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="sidebar sidebar-main" after="main">
        <container name="sidebar.main" as="sidebar_main" label="Sidebar Main"/>
    </container>
    <container name="div.sidebar.additional" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="sidebar sidebar-additional" after="div.sidebar.main">
        <container name="sidebar.additional" as="sidebar_additional" label="Sidebar Additional"/>
    </container>
  </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

Comment: So when i do this my page appears blank should it at least show something?

Comment: it is missing </layout>

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it doesn't include the `page-layout-2columns-left` body class. Because it includes the new layout class e.g. `page-layout-my-layout-file-name`. And the css for the 2columns-left layout is written with the `page-layout-2columns-left` class

To add this class to the body, you have to create a plugin for the `Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page` here is the code.

First create the `di.xml` in `Vendor/ModuleName/etc/frontend/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * di
 *
 * @copyright Copyright © 2022 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * @author    Vyacheslav Shmal
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">   
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page">
        <plugin name="pageLayoutDefaultClass" type="Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin\Result\Page"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

And then create the plugin class in `Vendor/ModuleName/Plugin/Result/Page.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * Page
 *
 * @copyright Copyright © 2023 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * @author    Vyacheslav Shmal
 */

namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin\Result;

use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page as ResultPage;

class Page
{

    /**
     * @param ResultPage $subject
     * @param ResponseInterface $response
     * @return array
     */
    public function beforeRenderResult(
        ResultPage $subject,
        ResponseInterface $response
    ) : array {
        // Apply the updated layout handles classes to the body when using our full width variants

        if ($subject->getConfig()->getPageLayout() == 'page-layout-my-layout-file-name') {
            $subject->getConfig()->addBodyClass('page-layout-2columns-left');
        }

        return [$response];
    }

}
```